# Why does the program skip cin.get() after a cin?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x,y;
   char direction ;
    char str1[10];
    cout<<"Please enter the initial position of the bot";
    cin>>x>>y;
    cout << "\n\n";
    cout << "enter initial direction in caps (F-forward,L-left,R-right)";
    cin >> direction;
    //cout << "chosen direction :" << direction ;
    cout << "\n\n";
    cout << "Enter the moves \n(Without space comma seperated in caps eg-F,L,L" ;
    cin.get(str1,10);
    cout << "entered moves :" << str1 << endl ;

    return 0;
}
```

after execution :
$ ./intern
Please enter the initial position of the bot1 2

enter initial direction in caps (F-forward,L-left,R-right)f

Enter the moves
(Without space comma seperated in caps eg-F,L,Lentered moves :

KARPAGAVALLI@Ashwin ~
$

Comment: Have you considered stepping through the code with a debugger?

Comment: I compiled it directly in the cygwin

Comment: "... the compiler exits ..." - No. The compiler does not exit, your *compiled* program does. The compilers job is finished long before you run into your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One issue here: after the last

```
cin >> direction;
```

there is an additional newline '\n' in the stream buffer, which is read by the next

```
cin.get(str1,10);
```

with the "illusion" that it was not executed. In fact, `str1` will be just the empty string.

The solution is to use

```
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

just before `cin.get(str1,10)` to clear the stream (note that you must `#include <limits>`).